# Copying files from somewhere within a directory tree to a folder

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, robocopy, xcopy

I have a mirror of a large website that I need to reorganize, most of the images and files I've been able to programmatically move and relink up; however, there are a few (few is a relative term, we're talking 3,000 odd files) I need to locate within the mess of folders.

I know the filename(s) (I have big long lists and I'm assuming they're unique, or at least unique enough that I can fix any collision manually) but not their location within the file structure, and I need to copy them to a separate directory so that I can then upload them.

In short, I have a list like

```
file1.jpg
file2.doc
file4.ppt
filesomethingelse.this
```

in a file (say, `filelist.txt`).

And I have a folder structure like

```
folder\subfolder\file1.jpg
folder\subfolder\file2.doc
folder\subfolder2\filesomethingelse.this
folder\file3.jpg
folder\file4.ppt
```

and I want to get

```
secondFolder\file1.jpg 
secondFolder\file2.doc
secondFolder\file4.ppt 
secondFolder\filesomethingelse.this
```

Note that `file3.jpg` should not be copied because it is not on the list.

Something command line like (xcopy or robocopy) would be the best option I guess, so I can batch up the requests.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to copy only those files whose names are listed in `filelist.txt`,
and skip files that aren't (e.g., `file3.jpg` in your example), do

```
for /r folder %f in (*) do @findstr/i /x "%~nxf" filelist.txt > nul && copy %f secondfolder
```

- `%f` is assigned the full pathname of each file under `folder`;
  `%~nxf` extracts the name and extension
  (i.e., the base filename; everything after the last `\`).
- `@` suppresses display of the following command. 
  This is cosmetic and discretionary.  Also, it is unnecessary
  if you put this command in a batch file and begin it with `@echo off`.
- `findstr` looks for a string (or pattern) in a file (or other data set); it is essentially Windows' equivalent of `grep`. 
  We use it to determine whether each filename is in the filename list,
  `filelist.txt`.

  - `/i` — Do case insensitive matching. 
    You can leave this out if you're sure your list has correct capitalization.
  - `/x` — Match entire line (like `grep -x`). 
    This prevents filenames like `le2.do` from matching `file2.doc`.
- `> nul` — equivalent to `> /dev/null`;
  this prevents the output from `findstr` from being displayed. 
  (Of course this is just to avoid cluttering the screen, and is optional.)
- `&&` — Do the next command (`copy`)
  if the previous command (`findstr`) succeeded. 
  (`findstr` succeeds if it finds a match; i.e., if the filename is in the list.)
- If you have any filenames with funny characters in them,
  you may need to put the last `%f` into quotes (`"%f"`)
  and maybe change the `findstr` command.
- Before you run this command for real,
  you might want to change `copy` to `echo copy`,
  so you can do a dry run and see what the command will do.
- If you put the command into a batch file,
  change all occurrences of `%` to `%%`.
- If you want to get a listing (log) of where the files were found, you can do

```
for /r folder %f in (*) do @findstr/i /x "%~nxf" filelist.txt > nul && (echo %f & copy %f secondfolder)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this:

```
for /R c:\source %f in (*) do copy "%f" x:\destination\
```

should do the job for you.